# try catch on HttpLinkServerException doesn't catch error

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, graphql, try-catch

I have a flutter application that uses graphql: ^5.0.0 to perform mutations and queries on my database and I'm trying to handle invalid token exceptions I get. When I get an invalid token error from my server, an error is thrown here.

[image: error being thrown here]

Here is the error making its way up into my code

[image: here is the throw in my code]

here is my code:

```
    try {
      final QueryResult result = await client.query(options);
      List<dynamic> taskList = result.data!['userTasksConnections']['tasks'];
      List<Task> tasks = [];
      for(int i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++) {
        tasks.add(Task.fromJson(taskList[i]));
      }
      return tasks;

    } on HttpLinkServerException catch(e) {
      if(e.parsedResponse?.errors?[0] == 'Invalid Token'){
        await UserRepo().getAccessToken();
        return getTasks(page: page, keyword: keyword);
      }
      else{
        return [];
      }
    }
```

since the error is clearly of type `HttpLinkServerException` I have an `on HttpLinkServerException catch()`. However, when the code runs the exception is not caught in the catch block and the code continues after the result `await` as if nothing happened, causing a `null` data exception on this line

```
      List<dynamic> taskList = result.data!['userTasksConnections']['tasks'];
```

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Comment: yes! I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own parser to fix this issue. You do so with something like this

```
import 'package:graphql/client.dart';

class CustomResponseParser extends ResponseParser {
  @override
  Response parseResponse(Map<String, dynamic> body) {
    Map<String, String> errors = new Map();
    if(body["errors"] != null) {
      errors['message'] = body["errors"][0];
    }
    Response res =  Response(
      errors: (body["errors"] as List?)
          ?.map(
            (dynamic error) => parseError(errors),
          )
          .toList(),
      data: body["data"] as Map<String, dynamic>?,
      context: Context().withEntry(
        ResponseExtensions(
          body["extensions"],
        ),
      ),
    );
    return res;
  }

  @override
  GraphQLError parseError(Map<String, dynamic> error) {
    return GraphQLError(
      message: error['message'],
    );
  }

}
```

And then you use it when initializing your graphqlClient like this

```
  final GraphQLClient client = GraphQLClient(
    cache: GraphQLCache(),
    link: AuthLink(getToken: () {
          if (store.state.auth.accessToken == '') {
            return "";
          } else {
            return "Bearer ${store.state.auth.accessToken}";
          }
        }).concat(
          HttpLink(
            Environment().config.apiHost,
            parser: CustomResponseParser()  
          )
        )
  );
```